# How to filter a JSON object with JQuery and create a new object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a `JSON` database that I need to filter and then be able to show a parameter (the `ActivityName`) of only the selected elements (by `Category`).

I need to be able to filter and obtain the `ActivitiesNames` of all the activities within a **category** depending on which the user selected.

I'm trying to create an object that has this filtered version of the database by doing this:

```
var selectedCategory = $(activitiesDatabase.Categories).filter(function(i, n)
{
    return n.CategoryID === selectedCategory;
});
```

But its not working apparently. Any thoughts as how can I solve this?

Thanks! (Below is a sample of the `JSON` database)

```
var activitiesDatabase = 
{
  "Categories": [
    { 
      "CategoryId": "cashFlow",
      "Activities": [ 
        {
          "ActivityName": "Measure and analyse cash flows" , 
          "EstimatedTime": 20
        },
        {
          "ActivityName": "Measure and analyse cash flows" , 
          "EstimatedTime": 20
        },
      ]
    },
    { 
      "CategoryId": "growthStrategies",
      "Activities": [ 
        {
          "ActivityName": "Research market and identify trends" , 
          "EstimatedTime": 30
        },
        {
          "ActivityName": "Research market and identify trends" , 
          "EstimatedTime": 30
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that get only the list of `activityNames` for some category using mainly the [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method of arrays. If you want all the object that wraps those activity names, this can be simplifyed.

```js
var activitiesDatabase = {"Categories": [
    {
        "CategoryId": "cashFlow",
        "Activities": [
            {"ActivityName": "Measure and analyse cash flows", "EstimatedTime": 20},
            {"ActivityName": "Measure and analyse cash flows", "EstimatedTime": 20},
        ]
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": "growthStrategies",
        "Activities": [ 
            {"ActivityName": "Research market and identify trends", "EstimatedTime": 30},
            {"ActivityName": "Research market and identify trends", "EstimatedTime": 30},
        ]
    },
]};

// Next method receive the array of categories, a category ID, and return
// the list of "Activity Names" related to that category.

const getActivityNamesByCategory = (catArray, catID) =>
{
    // Check arguments.

    catArray = (catArray.constructor === Array) ? catArray : [];

    // Generate output list.

    let actNames = catArray.reduce((res, curr) =>
    {
        if (curr.CategoryId == catID)
            curr.Activities.map((x) => res.push(x.ActivityName));

        return res;
    },
    []);

    return actNames;
};

// Test 1
let out1 = getActivityNamesByCategory(activitiesDatabase.Categories, "cashFlow");
console.log(out1);

// Test 2
let out2 = getActivityNamesByCategory(activitiesDatabase.Categories, "growthStrategies");
console.log(out2);

// Test wrong input 1
let out3 = getActivityNamesByCategory(activitiesDatabase, "asd");
console.log(out3);

// Test wrong input 2
let out4 = getActivityNamesByCategory(activitiesDatabase.Categories);
console.log(out4);
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much! A follow up while we are at it: I am allowing users to select several activities, and want to add up the activity EstimatedTimes.

Would it be a similar solution?

Comment: if you need also the `EstimatedTimes` try changing the `if` condition inside the `reduce` method to this one: `if (curr.CategoryId == catID) curr.Activities.map((x) => res.push(x));`

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's filter is designed to work with a set of matched DOM elements

You don't need jQuery for this, `Array.prototype.filter` will do the job:

```js
var activitiesDatabase = { "Categories": [ { "CategoryId": "cashFlow", "Activities": [ { "ActivityName": "Measure and analyse cash flows" , "EstimatedTime": 20 }, { "ActivityName": "Measure and analyse cash flows" , "EstimatedTime": 20 }, ] }, { "CategoryId": "growthStrategies", "Activities": [ { "ActivityName": "Research market and identify trends" , "EstimatedTime": 30 }, { "ActivityName": "Research market and identify trends" , "EstimatedTime": 30 }, ] }, ] };

const activitiesByCategoryId = categoryId => activitiesDatabase.Categories.filter(({ CategoryId }) => CategoryId === categoryId)

console.log(activitiesByCategoryId('cashFlow'))
```

Comment: I appreciate the terseness of an ES6 one liner, though I feel like someone who is trying to use jQuery for a straight forward array filtering could benefit with a more verbose execution 